# Determine if instance of UIViewController subclass exists

Tags: objective-c, ios, logging, uiviewcontroller, uikit

**How can I examine a list of all active objects that inherit UIViewController?**

I'd like to know if an instance of `MyViewController` exists. Ideally I can get this information in a callback in `UIApplicationDelegate` (for example application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:).

I've tried logging something like `navigationController.viewControllers` w/ no luck. I've also tried `topViewController` and `modalViewController` properties on navigationController.

Comment: Is this for debugging purposes or do you have something else in mind? and by "exists" do you mean exists and has a valid reference? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Jim it's for debugging. Yes I mean has a valid reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know for a fact that your rootViewController is a UINavigationController, you can iterate through the array of viewcontrollers and test it for a class type

```
BOOL success = NO;
NSArray *viewControllersArray = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
for (id vc in viewControllersArray)
{
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]])
        success = YES; // Found it!
}
```